# HLS streaming on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, galaxy

We are developing music streaming application for Android devices with adaptive bit rate support. We are using Wowza as streaming server which will stream songs using HLS. We have converted each song into four bitrates and have created smil files which are referred in HLS URLs. So basically final URL will look something like this.

http://streaming.server.name:1935/vod/smil:audiofile.smil/playlist.m3u8.

We have tested the app on multiple android devices ( Android version 4.0 or later ) including Galaxy S2, Galaxy Note I, Sony Experia, Google Nexus etc.. On all these devices the songs are getting streamed except on Galaxy S3. On Galaxy S3 the song starts and plays till 6 secs. After that the song goes in loop and plays again and again 6 sec part.

The same behavior is observed when the above URL is accessed through browser.

We have tried to check wowza logs but no errors were reported.

Has anyone tried such thing on S3 devices. Any guidance on how to debug this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Android documentation states (not clearly enough though) that the TS container format only supports AAC audio. Your are trying to play HLS with TS segments containing MP3 audio data (which is supported by iOS).

I can share the observation that doing so works on most Android devices, but not on all.
The S-III is an example of that.

Please refer to the [Android Supported Media Formats section](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I encoded the audio file in aac format within mp4 container. Now it is streaming fine on S3 as well as Note II and other devices I tested.